# Drupal 7 - Print & email Pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm using "Printer, email and PDF versions" Module (Drupal 7). Its functions are Print pages &  forward the page content through email. When i share a page to another person through email, the message is clipped in there inbox and reporting as Phishing , also images are not displaying.

We have to configure anything from admin side.? why does this issue occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email clients are typically configured not to show images by default for security reasons (Example: hide offensive images, block malicious/harmful images, etc).  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7489/why-would-someone-want-to-block-images-in-email.

Similarly, if an email client detects that the *From* address of your email doesn't match the actual server that sent it, then your email may be flagged as a phishing email.  See http://drupal.org/node/336038#comment-4735232.

Consider using a module like an [SMTP Authentication module](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) so that you can send emails through an smtp server such as Google's if you're using a Gmail address.